# How to avoid exception when padding on an empty string

Tags: c#, string, padding

Let's imagine `myString` is an empty `string` variable

When I try `myString.PadLeft(4, '0') ;`

Eventually , it will generate a `null reference exception` as I'm trying to call the padding on an empty object

But , is there a way in which if the string is empty just fill it with 4 zero in the padding option,  other than this "classic way" : `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString)?myString.PadLeft(4, '0'):"0000";`

Comment: `myString?.PadLeft(4, '0') ?? "0000"`

Comment: You don't get that exception if `myString` is empty.  You get it if it's `null`.

Comment: @ juharr so if my guess is right , just initializing the string could be a remedy ?

Comment: @NotADeveloper Can you write it as an answer so we can close it ?

Comment: The way to avoid an exception is to *validate* your input before working with it. So in your case check for null before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this by using null-coalescing operator

```
(myString??"").PadLeft(4, '0')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure `myString` is not null before padding. Cleanest way is to use [Null-coalescing Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/) like so:

```
(myString ?? "").PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and the [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) operators.

```
myString = myString?.PadLeft(4,'0') ?? "0000";
```